Can toga.Table colors be customized on Android?
I want to dispaly a preferences window with black background and yellow text, but the toga.Table does not render as it should on Andoid, or I don't know how to set colors. It seems that it ignore the colors I set in the style parameter. Any ideas ?
  ip_data = ['192.168.0.21', '192.168.0.30', '192.168.0.34']
  self.ip_list = toga.Table(headings=['Available WiFi adapters:'], data=ip_data, on_select=self.onIpSelect, style=Pack(background_color=clPrefBackg, color=clPrefBackg, font_size=12, flex=1))
  sel_ip_label = toga.Label("Server Address:", style=Pack(color=clPrefText))
  self.sel_ip = toga.Label("")
  self.container = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN, padding=10, flex=1))
  self.container.add(self.ip_list, sel_ip_label, self.sel_ip)
  self.PrefBox = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN, background_color=clPrefBackg))
  self.PrefBox.add(self.container)

Edit: Hmm... It seems that is something about the themes. I need to research it...

I think you're using the correct syntax, but it looks like the Table widget doesn't yet support custom text colors on Android. There is an implementation of background color, but it's possible it's being hidden by the backgrounds of the table rows.
